# What does nsurlsessiond transfer?

Tags: macos

nsurlsessiond makes numerous calls to apple.com over port 80. From other posts I have learned that some of this is iCloud, system updates and similar data. Is there some analysis available about what exact data is transmitted?

Comment: Official Apple Documentation on NS URL NSURLSESSOND: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession

Answer (score 3):

nsurlsessiond can be called by so many different things in different cases. You can monitor what's being downloaded using (requires SIP disabled):

```
sudo fs_usage -w | grep nsurlsessiond
```